# kivy - change things twice with one button click

Tags: python, button, kivy

wonder if anyone can help me out.

I am stuck with a problem. I want to change a buttons background_normal TWICE by clicking another button.

So for example first change to yellow than wait 2 seconds (time.sleep(2)) and then change to red.

I tried to make a simple functions that does this. But the problem is that it does not update the first change of the background_normal. It only displays the latest change.

Tried to split it into two functions, one changes it to the first color, the other one changes it to the second color. But still it does not display anything but the latest change.

Is there any possibility to solve this?

Update:
My code is ~2k lines so i will post a short form of my problem

```
class Game(FloatLayout):
    def firstaction(self):
        #change button1 to yellow and wait 2 seconds
    def secondaction(self):
        #change button1 to red


class GameApp(App):
     def build(self):
        return Game
```

kv file looks something like

```
button2:
    on_press: Game.firstaction
    on_press: Game.secondaction
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share the code you have written so far. It is easier to help that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You talk about colors so you should use background_color instead of background_normal. Going to the problem, the cause is `time.sleep()` because it blocks the event loop, the event loop helps the GUI to update due to OS or user events. The solution is to use `Clock`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        self.background_color = (1,1,0,1)
        fn = lambda dt: setattr(self, "background_color", (1,0,0,1))
        Clock.schedule_once(fn, 2) # <--- 2 seconds


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        button = MyButton(text='Hello World')
        return button

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: @DavidBrandstötter when someone asks you for a code, it does not ask you to publish your project, but technically it asks for a [mcve], if you see the code of my answer it's an MCVE if you change the `Clock.schedule_once(...)` with `time.sleep(2)`

Comment: yeah i will add code in the futere. and by the way it is not about color i just simplified it. It is about images for a playing card game where I created an AI (nnet combined with mcts) and now i want to enable people to play against this ai.

Comment: @DavidBrandstötter Actually the property is irrelevant, the central part of my answer is to use Clock, so your idea of background_normal is good because it abstracts us from the logic of your project. :)